# Is it possible to define an integral function and integrate it using `integral`?

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to do the following integration:

[image: \int_t^T\left{(T-u)sigma_{u}-(\int_u^T\lambda(T-s)e^{-\lambda s}ds)e^{\lambda u}\right}du]

In order to do integration using the function `integral` in matlab, I define the function

[image: \left{(T-u)sigma_{u}-(\int_u^T\lambda(T-s)e^{-\lambda s}ds)e^{\lambda u}\right}]

first and then apply `integral`. Below is my function:

```
OrderEpsilon2IntegrandIntegralIntegrand=@(T,s)lambda.*(T-s).*exp(-1.*lambda.*s);
OrderEpsilon2IntegrandIntegral=...
@(T,u)integral(@(t)OrderEpsilon2IntegrandIntegralIntegrand(T,t),u,T);

OrderEpsilon2Integrand=@(T,u)...
(T-u).*sigma(u).*v_0-...
OrderEpsilon2IntegrandIntegral(T,u).*exp(lambda.*u).*sigma(u).*v_0;

OrderEpsilon2Integral=...
@(t)arrayfun(@(T)integral(OrderEpsilon2Integrand(T,u),InitialTime,T),t);
```

However, I have the following error message:

```
Error using integral (line 85)
A and B must be floating-point scalars.

Error in (T,u)integral(@(t)OrderEpsilon2IntegrandIntegralIntegrand(T,t),u,T)

Error in @(T,u)(T-u).*sigma(u).*v_0-OrderEpsilon2IntegrandIntegral(T,u).*exp(lambda.*u).*sigma(u).*v_0

Error in @(u)OrderEpsilon2Integrand(2.3,u)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
            fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
        [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

What's the problem to make such error occurs? I have no ideas on the message. Also, I would like to know how to correct the codes. However, there are some constraints on correcting the codes:

First, do not write

[image: \int_u^T \lambda(T-s)e^{-\lambda s}ds)e^{\lambda u}]

explicitly.

Second, do not use `integral2`. If possible, I would like to define the integrand having the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?:

```
syms s u T t sg lm
%%sg=u^2+u+1; %%Define sigma expression in here
f=int((T-u)*sg-int(lm*(T-s)*exp(-lm*s),s,u,T)*exp(lm*u),u,t,T)
```

Resulting in:

```
T*t + T/lm + (T^2*sg)/2 - t/lm + (sg*t^2)/2 - T^2/2 - 1/lm^2 - t^2/2 + (exp(-T*lm)*exp(lm*t))/lm^2 - T*sg*t
```

Comment: It is because ultimately, I want to compute,e.g, OrderEpsilon2Integral([1,2,3,4]). Defining symbolic cannot help me to compute OrderEpsilon2Integral([1,2,3,4]), am I right?

Comment: No, you can ultimately make a `for` cycle, which without vectorization would be solved without any issue through any standard processor?